# How to refactor logging statements in sibling classes (in this case)?

Tags: java, hadoop, logging

Take these code snippets in Hadoop as examples:

Line **780**,  public void deleteAsUser(DeletionAsUserContext ctx)
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/e6b74164e9fc50518e03629c99525c2136c01593/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/LinuxContainerExecutor.java
and Line **622**, public void deleteAsUser(DeletionAsUserContext ctx)
https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/3d65dbe032e202361d613344ccc6d9c5f99ba395/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-server/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/server/nodemanager/DefaultContainerExecutor.java

Both of these two classes extend abstract class "ContainerExecutor.java". We can see that these two methods are not so similar, and both of them have same logging statements, LOG.info("Deleting path : " + del);:

LinuxContainerExecutor.java

```
for (Path baseDir : baseDirs) {
    Path del = dir == null ? baseDir : new Path(baseDir, dir);
    LOG.info("Deleting path : " + del);
    pathsToDelete.add(del.toString());
    deleteAsUserOp.appendArgs(baseDir.toUri().getPath());
  }
```

DefaultContainerExecutor.java

```
for (Path baseDir : baseDirs) {
  Path del = subDir == null ? baseDir : new Path(baseDir, subDir);
  LOG.info("Deleting path : " + del);
  try {
    if (!lfs.delete(del, true)) {
      LOG.warn("delete returned false for path: [" + del + "]");
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Will it be better if I extract the log string from these two logging statements to their parent class and use the variable to replace the original log message, so that if I want to improve the log message in the future I can just modify the variable (if not, one of them might be easily forgotten to be changed and the logs will be inconsistent).

For example:

```
String DELETE_PATH_LOG = "Deleting path : ";
```

Or if there's some other way to improve this case?

Comment: What's wrong with how it currently is?

Comment: It is not about this is right or wrong. This is an example that I find regarding a possibility for log refactoring. This kind of duplicate logs can increase log maintenance difficulties (e.g., changing a log line may break existing log analysis scripts, and we might forget to change due to log duplication), my question is if there is a better way to refactor this kind of log lines.